# Find command in shell with regular expression to find files with two extensions

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I am trying to list generated log and zip files from my application server.

- Files which are .log or .zip
- These files include digits in their name. i.e. Files with any number of digits in their name
- Files should be older than +5 days.

I used below expression. but looks something wrong. Could you please assist with regular expression?

```
ROOT_DIR=applications/jboss-as/servers/
find $ROOT_DIR -name '*[0-9]*[zip|log]' -mtime +5
```

Finally I wish to delete these files using command

```
find $ROOT_DIR -name '*[0-9]*[zip|log]' -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Why do you think that `-name` takes a regex?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  tried -name '*[0-9]' and it worked.

Comment: But that's not even a regex.

Comment: got it. I am trying -regex '*[0-9]*[zip|log]'

Comment: You've chosen the [tag:unix] tag; does that mean you're not on Linux, or that you're interested in portability?  The significance is the GNU `find` is found on Linux and can do things one way, while non-Linux platforms often use a different implementation of `find` and cannot do all the same things that GNU `find` can do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I am on Linux only- Red Hat Linux

Comment: Of course, `[zip|log]` is not a useful regex for this, either.  It will match a single character out of the set `gilopz|` (reordered alphabetically for illustration).  For what it's worth, this is covered in the [`regex` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) among the common newbie mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The first command will find them and display.

```
find $ROOT_DIR ! -readable -prune -mtime +5 -type f |  egrep -e "^.*\.(log|zip)$"
```

The second one will remove them all

```
find $ROOT_DIR ! -readable -prune -mtime +5 -type f |  egrep -e "^.*\.(log|zip)$" | xargs -L 1 rm
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way (with most versions of `find`):

```
find "$ROOT_DIR" '(' -name '*[0-9]*.log' -o -name '*[0-9]*.zip' ')' -mtime +5 -exec rm {} +
```

The `+` is from POSIX 2008 and means "run the exec'd command with as many file names as convenient" whereas the older alternative `';'` (or `\;`) means "run the exec'd command once per file name".

If you have GNU [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Regular-Expressions), you can use various dialects of regular expression:

```
find "$ROOT_DIR" -regex '.*\.\(zip\|bz2\)' -mtime +5 -delete
```

This uses the default regex mode; you can use some alternatives to avoid using so many backslashes.  The `-delete` option uses the `unlink()` system call rather than invoking an external command; it is more efficient, therefore.